# AWS Lambda python API call method not returning JSON - not serialisable?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, restful-architecture

I have a Lambda function, which is a basic Python GET call to an API. It works fine locally, however when I upload to Lambda (along with the requests library) it will not return the JSON response from the API call. I simply want it to return the entire JSON object to the caller. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here - I stumbled across a couple of articles saying that returning JSON from a Lambda Python function is not supported.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import json
url = "http://url/api/projects/"
headers = {
   'content-type': "application/json",
   'x-octopus-apikey': "redacted",
   'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    return response
```

My package contains the requests library and dist, and the json library (I don't think it needs this though). Error message returned is:

```
    {
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py",
      251,
      "dumps",
      "sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)"
    ],
    [
      "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py",
      207,
      "encode",
      "chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)"
    ],
    [
      "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py",
      270,
      "iterencode",
      "return _iterencode(o, 0)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py",
      41,
      "decimal_serializer",
      "raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "<Response [200]> is not JSON serializable"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've resolved this - the problem with my Python code is that it was trying to return the *entire* response, rather than simply the JSON body (the code for my local version prints 'response.text'). In addition, I have ensured that the response is JSON formatted (rather than raw text). Updated code:

```
import requests
import json
url = "http://url/api/projects/"
headers = {
   'content-type': "application/json",
   'x-octopus-apikey': "redacted",
   'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)           
    try:
        output = response.json()
    except ValueError:
        output = response.text
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same error and for a while I was able to solve this by changing the response code in Lambda python3.6:

Change : `response['Body'].read()` to `response['Body'].read().decode()`

This way you will get a JSON though in my case I got `/` everywhere which I removed later.